# Draw directly to the root window with PyCairo

Tags: python, linux, cairo

I want to be able to draw directly to the root window in Python using Cairo. I have tested my code drawing on a fullscreened window, so I know that's not the issue. However, when I try to draw directly to the root window like so:

```
root = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
cr = root.cairo_create()
...
# Drawing code here
```

nothing happens. The code runs fine, but nothing is ever drawn to the screen. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to overlay a transparent window on top of everything? (The issue with that solution is multi-monitor setups)

Comment: Are you running some kind of desktop environment, such as gnome? They use a full-screen desktop window that actually covers over the real root window. You don't see the root window when these environments are running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934442/drawing-on-the-x-root-window

here some perl that can find desktop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934442/drawing-on-the-x-root-window

here some perl that can find desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual root window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_window#Virtual_root_window).

Note that KDE4 doesn't follow this convention. You need to find a child of the root window which has a property _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE set to _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP.